# Java .wav sounds don't work properly

Tags: java, audio, wav

I'm having sound problems in a game i'm making in java. I have a class called SoundSystem which contains Objects called Sound which is where i'm reading the sound files. Here's the class Sound for your intake.

```
package soundSystem;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;


public class Sound {

private Clip clip;
private boolean isPlaying;
private boolean loop;

public Sound(boolean loop, String file){
    this.loop = loop;
    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        URL url = getClass().getResource(file);
        AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        clip.open(input);

    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean getIsPlaying(){
    return isPlaying;
}

public void play(){
    if(clip == null ) return;
    clip.stop();
    clip.flush();
    clip.setFramePosition(1800);
    clip.start();
}

public void close(){
    clip.stop();
    clip.close();
}

public void update(){
    isPlaying = clip.isRunning();
    if(!isPlaying){
        if(loop)
            play();
        else 
            clip.stop();
    } 
}
}
```

As you see i'm reading the files as URL because i'm exporting the project as runnable Jar File and it is the best way I've found, still that has nothing to do with the problem i'm having.

Now here's the problem. If I read a unique sound or music, for instance a sound at the start of a level or a music playing the whole level, it works completely fine. I have yet to find a problem in that situation. Things start to go wrong when there are repetitive sounds being played. Say a shooting sound that you can shoot as much as you can click on keyboard per second, the movement sound, explosions sound, etc... Those sounds a lot of the times work but sometimes don't. It becomes even more apparent with the shooting sound which sometimes you wont even hear in several seconds of continued firing. Sometimes even an unique sound at the end of the level/game over, will also not work. But that one I don't know the cause or the difference that it makes with the start of the level.

I've tried altering the sound files with audacity cutting or adding extra space to the sound before its start. I've tried messing with frame rate by setting it at a determined time. Even changing how they're read, but no matter what I do it always persists and remains consistent.

So if you might know whats going on or have any advice feel free to answer. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your way of playing a Sound seems a bit off to me. I have found that This example works best to play a sound file. Maybe it will work better for your repeatable sounds. http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-audio-example-java-au-play-sound

Comment: The link doesn't help for it is just a how to play an audio sound. My class allows the sound to be looped(music mostly), where the update() method simply checks when to loop again. When i'm calling normal sounds, even repetitive sounds I use the method play(). those are the main differences but other then that there is nothing unusual about it.

Comment: Mmm well I feel like the way your resources are handled is a bit off. Perhaps it is a threading issue. You are playing this off the mainthread? Have you tried closing the clip differently? By a linelistener for instance.

Comment: How do I use that said LineListener? I've found what you said in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036843/clip-sometimes-does-not-play  I've added the line listener as shown but now when I play a clip first time, it never plays again. Before my play function could reset it as they say but now it can't with the added LineListener. Like they also say in that thread, I have many sounds being played and they say that creates lag. But then what about thousands of games that have hundreds of sounds, doesn't make sense.

Comment: Since this problem only occurs in sounds that are repeated quickly? How about creating several instances of the same sound. So that when one is playing, a different one is played? Do you think that could do the trick? Would there be an efficient way to do so?

Comment: Yes I think that is possible. Make sure you don't play a sound in your mainthread. If it is a background process it shouldn't create any lag. Creating several instances of the same sound is fine. I suggest you try Steven Lukes approach in https://coderanch.com/t/598626/java/play-sound-clip-time

Comment: I solved it with the idea I had on using several instances of the same sound. I'll post it as an answer so others may see it and may find it useful. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved this by creating several instances of the same sound. May sound strange so i'll just post the code.

```
package soundSystem;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Sound {

private Clip[] clip;
private boolean isPlaying;
private boolean loop;
private int maxC;
private int c;

public Sound(boolean loop, String file, int nrReplications){
    this.loop = loop;
    maxC = nrReplications;
    c = 0;
    clip = new Clip[maxC];
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < maxC){
            clip[i] = AudioSystem.getClip();
            URL url = getClass().getResource(file);
            AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            clip[i].open(input);
            ++i;
        }
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean getIsPlaying(){
    return isPlaying;
}

public void play(){
    if(clip == null ) return;
    if(c == maxC)
        c = 0;
    clip[c].stop();
    //clip.flush();
    clip[c].setMicrosecondPosition(0);
    //clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip[c].start();
    ++c;
}

public void close(){
    clip[c].stop();
    clip[c].close();
}

public void update(){
    isPlaying = clip[0].isRunning();
    if(!isPlaying){
        if(loop)
            play();
        else 
            clip[0].stop();
    } 
}
}
```

As you can see I created an array of Clips and used a counter on them. Unique sounds like I had previously said are given a 1 on nrReplications. But other sounds like selecting options, explosions, movements, are given 2+ and the player shots were given 5. At 5 I could see no more increase in quality so I left it like that.

It is also worth noting that even though I removed flush(); and changed framePosition to microSecondPosition in the play() method, that made no difference on the sound working properly, I just left them commented...

Anyways, if you're having the same problem now you know what might solve it. Worked like a charm for me. Finally listening all those shots per second working perfectly, oh man, feels gud.