# Audio Clip occasionally not playing

Tags: java, audio

I have created an audio clip ([`javax.sound.sampled.Clip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html)) using the following code:

```java
public Clip getClip() throws Exception {
    AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("test.wav"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(in);
    return clip;
}
...
this.clip = getClip();
```

And I am repeatedly triggering playback of [the clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9lEqEm5g0vvelI2NGNGWTZ0RlE/view?usp=sharing) with:

```java
public void play() {
    clip.stop();
    clip.flush();
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
}
```

I am testing this by using a `JFrame` and calling `play()` on every key press ([full test class here](https://gist.github.com/jmariner/3f1110443763416c8528bc9d23576f9b)). The majority of the time, the sound plays with every key press, no matter how quickly keys are pressed. But sometimes, when keys are pressed in rapid succession, the sound skips one of the key presses and just doesn't play at all. This is implemented in a game, so consistent sound playback is rather important.

Researching this problem brought me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30036843/8161100), which suggested closing the line every time its playback ends, as such:

```java
clip.addLineListener(e -> {
    if (e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) e.getLine().close();
});
```

But that just stopped playback all-together after this first time.

Other things that I've tried:

- Various combinations of [`.stop()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#stop--), [`.flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#flush--), and [`.drain()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#drain--) in `play()`.
- Using [`java.applet.AudioClip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/AudioClip.html) instead of `Clip`
- Re-creating the Clip object on each play (this just led to delayed playback each time)

I've tested a few PCs and this issue seems to be less prominent, or at least less noticeable, on higher-end PCs. If this is the case, is there anything that can be done to improve the playback consistency on lower-end systems? If the implementation is the issue here, what would be the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the `Clip` just doesn't afford the level of granularity that you need. I don't think there are any particular requirements for `Clip` in this respect. `SourceDataLine` will block if the buffer size is too big, so it could be that `Clip` has something similar going on like that, but `Clip` doesn't let you specify the internal buffer size.

If it were me, I'd write my own `Clip`-like object using a `SourceDataLine` so I could specify a particular buffer size, probably one that writes at roughly the same frame rate as the game or some fraction of it.

```
int bytesPerSecond = (int) fmt.getSampleRate()
                         * fmt.getFrameSize();
int targetGameFPS  = 30;
int bufferSize     = bytesPerSecond / targetGameFPS;
```

Note that using a buffer that's *too* small may result in artifacts like clicking or tearing on slower computers.

Then you make sure to also call [`sourceDataLine.open(audioFmt, bufferSize)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html#open-javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat-int-) with this buffer size.

The downside is that you need to write `start` and `stop` controls yourself, using a background thread and synchronization. (This very isn't hard, but it does mean it isn't exactly a simple solution.)

I can't say for sure that this will solve the problem, but it's probably what I would try next. (Writing your own audio player does also have the benefit of being much more flexible in the long-run. `Clip` doesn't have a very impressive feature set to begin with.)

Comment: Good answer. I added some notes in my answer (there is a circuitous way to specify a buffer size for a Clip), and wanted to invite you to also check out AudioCue.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote looks fine to me. I'm not sure you need the `flush` method but when I commented it out, it did not help performance.

If I understand Radiodef's theory, the time to execute an internal buffer for the `Clip` may be larger than the amount of time between keystrokes if they are very close together. `Clips` and `SourceDataLines` are both notorious for not allowing changes except at buffer boundaries. (Can be really annoying if trying to perform a volume fade, for example.)

There *is* a way to specify the buffer size of the `Clip`. The API is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#open(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,%20byte[],%20int,%20int))

```
open(AudioFormat format, byte[] data, int offset, int bufferSize)
```

It may very well work in your case to specify a low buffer size, though the risk of dropouts will increase, especially if there are other sounds playing. To be honest I haven't experimented with this way of loading and playing `Clips`. Note that you have to have the PCM data in a byte array, in order to use this method. I've seen questions on how to do this here at StackOverflow.

Another solution is to use the keystroke capture method to load an array (possibly include time stamps) and have another process that executes audio plays from that array. Then you could tinker with the minimum required time needed between plays to ensure that each stroke has an associated play.

What I'd like to offer as an alternative is to use [AudioCue](http://adonax.com/AudioCue/). I understand you are doing this as a learning project, and might be reluctant on that basis to use a pre-written class. In this case, though, the source available, so you can freely examine and edit/tinker with the code. There are three files involved, the main class, and an Interface and helper class for implementing a Listener.

`AudioCue` has exactly the capability that Radiodef is recommending. The class loads the media data into an array and plays it via a `SourceDataLine`. When you `open` the `AudioCue`, there is a method that allows you to optionally specify the buffer size. `AudioCue` can be played like a `Clip`, with stopping, resetting and starting a single instance, but it also supports concurrent playback and has some additional features (e.g., real time volume, panning, playback speed faders that respond on a per-frame basis, not just at buffer boundaries).

If nothing else, you can look at the code and see and example of how to implement a `Clip`-like via a `SourceDataLine` as Radiodef has suggested.